# Why is Capistrano not installing gems with bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, bundler, gemfile

Every time I deploy an app with Capistrano, it complains about missing gems.
For example:

```
 ** [out :: mysite.com] Could not find WhateverGem-1.0.0 in any of the sources
 ** [out :: mysite.com] Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I resolve this by manually uploading my Gemfile, SSHing into the server, and running `bundle install`. However, this should not be happening.

Here's a copy of my [deploy.rb](https://gist.github.com/2860967) and [Capfile](https://gist.github.com/2860959).

Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You probably just need to add this to your config/deploy.rb

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
```

Comment: Thanks! That solves the problem with bundling, but I still get the following error when trying to migrate the database: `Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (mysql2 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)` It's already included in my Gemfile (and I'm using the mysql2 adapter in the `database.yml` file) but I don't see it when I look inside the shared/bundle folder. Any ideas what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: turns out this was a weird version control issue. The Gemfile that was being pushed to the server didn't contain the `mysql2` Gem... Not sure why.

Comment: Sometimes you do more silly things than you expect from yourself. In my case, I never pushed the code and gems were never getting installed. Just in case it helps. Great answer anyways.