# Capistrano deploy:migrate Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, rails-migrations

My Capistrano deploy:migrate task is set to run a simple rake db:migrate command, as follows:

```
env PATH=/home/user/.gems/bin sh -c 'cd /home/user/app/releases/20121003140503 && rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate'
```

When I run this task during an ssh session manually it completes successfully.  However when I run from my local development box, I receive the following error:

```
** [out :: app] Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
```

I am able to locate my rake gem by typing `which rake` via ssh (/home/user/.gems/bin/rake) and `rake --version` gives me "rake, version 0.9.2.2," so I don't understand why this command fails via Capistrano?

Comment: did you find the answer to this? I have the same problem and the proposal below doesn't help me...

Answer (score 3):

Capistrano does not place `bundle exec` before `rake` command in default. If you are sure you have the rake gem in your bundle, try adding this to your `deploy.rb`.

```
set :rake, 'bundle exec rake'
```

This will tell Capistrano to instead of just `rake` run `bundle exec rake`. If it is in your bundle, you won't have any problems any more and you will also avoid collisions if you have more versions of rake installed on your system.

Answer (score 0):

You might also just need to bundle your gems with this:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
```

Via: [Why is Capistrano not installing gems with bundler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10867383/why-is-capistrano-not-installing-gems-with-bundler)

Answer (score 0):

Once you go into your app folder, you simply type:
`$bundle exec rake` instead of just `$rake`